# How to make an ImageView the same height as the LinearLayout, but keep original aspect ratio which makes the width wider than the LinearLayout

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-linearlayout, android-imageview

I'm in a horizontal LinearLayout (landscape app). I have an image that is 5000x1080px for a scrolling home screen background. I need the image to fill the height of the LinearLayout while maintaining the image's original ratio. This will obviously cause the width to overlap with the outside edges of the Layout, and with that I will be able to animate it with a Translation to achieve a "scrolling" effect.

I've tried a bunch of different combinations of scaleType and adjustViewBounds but I can't seem to get the desired effect. The ImageView seems to constantly fill both the height and the width while maintaining the image's ratio, but not making the height match the parent as desired.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
    android:background="@color/black"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/homeBackground"
        android:src="@drawable/background_home"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:alpha="0.7"/>
```

Comment: Did you read the quality suggestions before you posted this? Please see: [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags)

Comment: I'm not sure why you removed the Android-Studio tag when Android Studio is what I am using in development.

Comment: That tag is only for questions about the tool itself, not for general Android development questions. You should have been notified of that fact before you submitted this question. Did you read the notice?

Comment: Okay that makes sense, sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer: constraintLayout on the dimensions with a ratio equal to the image's dimensions:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/homeBackground"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:alpha="0.7"
        android:src="@drawable/background_home"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="4.629629:1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Since the image's dimensions are 5000x1080, that comes out to a 125:27 ratio, then simplified to 4.629629:1 or (125/27:1)